# Can i update to ruby 2.2 with rails 3.2.22?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I was using **rails 3.2.11** with **ruby 1.9.3**, i was trying to change the version.

My question is if i am going to use **ruby 2.2** with **rails 3.2.22**, is there any chances to fail anywhere?

what will be the impact? will it be any problem with delayed job anything like that?

Comment: Did you check the Rails site for language compatibility?

Comment: No, where can i check that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not Ruby version dependant on Rails version, but vice versa.

> what will be the impact?

With your case chances are there will be problems, because [Rails 3.2.13 supports Ruby 2.0](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2013/2/27/Rails-3-2-13-rc1-has-been-released/) and [Rails 3.2.22 supports Ruby 2.2](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2015/6/16/Rails-3-2-22-4-1-11-and-4-2-2-have-been-released-and-more).

For the below Rails versions recommended Ruby version is 1.9.3.

So you could (should) upgrade the Rails version to at least 3.2.22 to use Ruby 2.2. This won't be a hard upgrade, since changes would be rather minor.

Comment: yes, that is my plan i am going to change my ruby to 2.2 and also change the rails to 3.2.22, the main thing i am looking to ruby 2.2 with new GC feature